# ts-sinon: Property 'returns' does not exist on type

Tags: javascript, typescript, mocha.js, sinon

I am writing an application using Typescript, and want to create unit tests with  [ts-sinon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-sinon).

In their README, they state that you can stub methods like this:

```
import * as sinon from 'ts-sinon'

class Test {
    method() { return 'original' }
}

const test = new Test();
const testStub = sinon.stubObject<Test>(test);

testStub.method.returns('stubbed');

expect(testStub.method()).to.equal('stubbed');
```

But this code gives me this error:

> Property 'returns' does not exist on type '() => string'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know `typescript` or `sinon`, but the code example has `const stubObject = sinon.stubObject;`, along with `import * ...`, which yours seems to be missing. Could that be the issue?

Comment: I tried doing that, but that also results in the error. It should not make any difference, as calling a function assigned to a variable is the same as calling the function directly.

Comment: Oh sorry, I see that my code had an error, i updated `stubMethod` to be `sinon.stubMethod`, my bad. The error is still there though.

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar issue, and this post was a false positive for me. I thought it worth pointing out that when I put the code in the following test, it works as expected.

```js
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type */
import * as chai from 'chai'
import * as sinon from 'ts-sinon'
const expect = chai.expect

class Test {
  public method() : string {return `original`}
}

const test = new Test()

describe.only(`ts-sinon stubObject()<Test> should`, () => {
  it(`return the expected value`, () => {
    const testStub = sinon.stubObject<Test>(test)
    testStub.method.returns(`stubbed`)
    expect(testStub.method()).to.equal(`stubbed`)
  })
})
```

The problem I was having involved not setting the correct type for my stub. The following example adds a `beforeEach` and scopes the stub at a higher level. It was setting the incorrect stub type that caused my "Property returns does not exist" error.

```js
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type */
import * as chai from 'chai'
import * as sinon from 'ts-sinon'
const expect = chai.expect

class Test {
  public method() : string {return `original`}
}

describe.only(`ts-sinon stubObject()<Test> should`, () => {
  let testStub: sinon.StubbedInstance<Test> // <- Type the stub correctly
  beforeEach(() => {
    const test = new Test()
    testStub = sinon.stubObject<Test>(test)
    testStub.method.returns(`stubbed`)
  })
  it(`return the expected value`, () => {
    expect(testStub.method()).to.equal(`stubbed`)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to define the stubObject as:

```
import * as sinon from "ts-sinon";

const stubObject = sinon.stubObject;
```

Comment: I tried that but it gives the same result. That is logical, I don't really understand why they assign the function to this variable. The end result is completely the same.

Comment: As you are importing all the modules using * and assigning it to sinon, we need to get the stubObject out of sinon to use this in - const testStub = stubObject<Test>(test);

Comment: Oh sorry, I see that my code had an error, i updated `stubMethod` to be `sinon.stubMethod`, my bad. The error is still there though.